# Get max date from another table based on date of current row

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have two tables, `CALL_DATA` and `MASTER_DATA`.

Master data has daily data of a customer and `CALL_DATA` has some calls of customer along with some other data.
I want to get for every customer and for every daily row of him in `MASTER_DATA` the row with the most recent date (maximum date till now) from `CALL_DATA`.

I have come up with this:

```
SELECT MAX(CALL_DATA.CALL_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY MASTER_DATA.CUSTOMER_ID 
                                          ORDER BY MASTER_DATA.DAILY_START_DATE)
        AS max_date_agg
     , MASTER_DATA.*
     , CALL_DATA.*
  FROM MASTER_DATA, CALL_DATA
 WHERE CALL_DATA.CALL_DAT <= MASTER_DATA.DAILY_START_DATE 
   AND CALL_DATA.CUSTOMER_ID = MASTER_DATA.CUSTOMER_ID;
```

But this returns me more than one live for every daily start date.
In fact it returns  as many rows as there are inside `CALL_DATA` table up until the `DAILY_START_DATE` in `MASTER_DATA`.

Example :

```
   MAX_DATE_AGG             CUSTOMER_ID  DAILY_START_DATE
24/10/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   24/10/17 00:00:00
24/10/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   25/10/17 00:00:00
24/10/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   26/10/17 00:00:00
24/10/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   27/10/17 00:00:00
24/10/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   28/10/17 00:00:00
24/10/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   29/10/17 00:00:00
24/10/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   30/10/17 00:00:00
24/10/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   31/10/17 00:00:00
24/10/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   01/11/17 00:00:00
24/10/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   02/11/17 00:00:00
24/10/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   03/11/17 00:00:00
24/10/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   04/11/17 00:00:00
24/10/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   05/11/17 00:00:00
24/10/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   06/11/17 00:00:00
24/10/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   07/11/17 00:00:00
24/10/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   08/11/17 00:00:00
24/10/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   09/11/17 00:00:00
24/10/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   10/11/17 00:00:00
24/10/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   11/11/17 00:00:00
24/10/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   12/11/17 00:00:00
24/10/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   13/11/17 00:00:00
24/10/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   14/11/17 00:00:00
15/11/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   15/11/17 00:00:00
15/11/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   15/11/17 00:00:00
15/11/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   16/11/17 00:00:00
15/11/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   16/11/17 00:00:00
15/11/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   17/11/17 00:00:00
15/11/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   17/11/17 00:00:00
15/11/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   18/11/17 00:00:00
15/11/17 00:00:00,000000000 100664970   18/11/17 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should return this what you want

```
SELECT T.*
  FROM (
          SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY MASTER_DATA.CUSTOMER_ID, MASTER_DATA.DAILY_START_DATE ORDER BY CALL_DATA.CALL_DATE DESC) AS myrank,
                MASTER_DATA.CUSTOMER_ID,
                MASTER_DATA.DAILY_START_DATE,
                CALL_DATA.CALL_DATE
           FROM MASTER_DATA,
                CALL_DATA
          WHERE CALL_DATA.CALL_DATE   <= MASTER_DATA.DAILY_START_DATE 
            AND CALL_DATA.CUSTOMER_ID = MASTER_DATA.CUSTOMER_ID
       ) T
 WHERE myrank = 1  
  ;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can convert your query to correlated sub query:

```
SELECT MASTER_DATA.*, (
    SELECT MAX(CALL_DATE)
    FROM CALL_DATA
    WHERE CALL_DATA.CUSTOMER_ID = MASTER_DATA.CUSTOMER_ID
    AND CALL_DATA.CALL_DAT <= MASTER_DATA.DAILY_START_DATE
) AS MOST_RECENT_CALL_TILL_NOW
FROM MASTER_DATA
```